# How to run XNA rendering on Azure workerrole?

Tags: c#, azure, 3d, xna, rendering

We want to use an Azure workerrole to render 3D images and combine those into a video. At the moment we're using a tool written with XNA to render the images and FFMpeg to combine it in a video.

So the problem is that Azure's workerrole is headless and doesn't have any graphic adapters as seen in this exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.NoSuitableGraphicsDeviceException: Could not find a Direct3D device that supports the XNA Framework Reach profile.
>
> Verify that a suitable graphics device is installed.

When using remote desktop to access the workerrole the program runs fine and everything works as expected.

What I've already tried is using a reference device by setting `GraphicsAdapter.UseReferenceDevice` to true so it uses the CPU instead of GPU. This also works on remote desktop but again not on the workerrole itself. It looks like to me like the problem is there isn't a graphic context available to make XNA work in instead of something with hardware acceleration.

**To make a long story short:** is there a way to use XNA rendering on a workerrole without remote desktop?